# How to access a variable within an array

Tags: php, arrays, oop, multidimensional-array

I have a vardump that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [downloadsLeft] => 0
        )

)
```

It's stored in the variable `$downloadsOBJ`

How would I access the downloadsLeft variable within that array and store it in a new variable:

e.g.

```
$downloadsLeft = $downloadsOBJ['downloadsLeft'];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe `$downloadsLeft = $downloadsOBJ[0]->downloadsLeft;` because stdClass is an object, not an array..

Comment: `$downloadsOBJ` itself is an array.

Comment: Haha, oops, my bad. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 6):

`$downloadsLeft = $downloadsOBJ[0]->downloadsLeft;` should do the trick